# JSTL nested expression issue in JSP

Tags: jsp, jstl

I am new to jstl with jsp.I have the following requirement where i have to evaluate nested jstl expression.Please have a look on the code below.

```
<c:forEach varStatus="status" begin="0" end="19">
<input type="text"
value="${dataTableVo.orderList[${status.index}].mtocCode}" --->Problem area
</c:forEach>
```

I should be able to fetch value using the expression ${dataTableVo.orderList[${status.index}].mtocCode}.
But it does not work.I should not use items attribute in foreach loop here.
The values should be as follows.
${dataTableVo.orderList[0].mtocCode}.
${dataTableVo.orderList[1].mtocCode}..... so on till 19.
Please share any ideas for this scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to nest it like that. Just write as one expression:

```
${dataTableVo.orderList[status.index].mtocCode}
```